# How to reduce this script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am quite new to Jquery and Javascript but i ve created a script which communicates with a php controller in symfony2.

My question is, what can i do to reduce the script length --> maybe there is a smarter way to solve the logic which i solved with the switch expression?

Thanks

```
/**
 * This function gets the current clicked buttons value and post it to the given action + returns the correct value
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.rating-button').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $element   = $(this).attr('id');
        var $rating    = $(this).attr('value');
        var $messageId = $(this).closest('ul').next('input:hidden').val();

        if(typeof $rating !== 'undefined' && $rating != null) {
            $.post(Routing.generate('rating_vote', { 'messageId': $messageId, 'ratingCode': $rating }),
            function($json) {
                $('button#'+$element).parent().find('span').text($json.numberOfRatings);

                /* check if oldRating is defined and oldRating is not the same as new rating ( prevent decrease of actual value if this is the first vote entry for the current message and the specific user ) */
                if(typeof $json.oldRating !== 'undefined' && $json.oldRating != null && ($json.oldRating != $rating) ) {
                    switch($json.oldRating) {
                        case 1:
                            $oldElement = 'rating-first';
                            break
                        case 2:
                            $oldElement = 'rating-second';
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $oldElement = 'rating-third';
                            break;
                    }
                    $('button#'+$oldElement).parent().find('span').text(Number($('button#'+$oldElement).parent().find('span').text()) -1);
                }

            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This is better suited for code-review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace your switch case logic with [this rather neat concept](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/how-to-avoid-switch-case-syndrome/).

```
$(function() {
    $('button.rating-button').on('click',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            element   = $this.attr('id'),
            rating    = $this.attr('value'),
            messageId = $this.closest('ul').next('input:hidden').val();
        if(typeof rating !== 'undefined' && rating != null) {
            $.post(Routing.generate('rating_vote', { 'messageId': messageId, 'ratingCode': rating }),
                function(json) {
                    $('button#'+element).parent().find('span').text(json.numberOfRatings);
                    if(typeof json.oldRating !== 'undefined' && json.oldRating != null && (json.oldRating != rating) ) {
                        var oldElement = ({
                            1: 'rating-first',
                            2: 'rating-second',
                            3: 'rating-third'
                        })[json.oldRating];
                        $('button#'+oldElement).parent().find('span').text(Number($('button#'+oldElement).parent().find('span').text()) -1);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Some general thoughts:

- when using jQuery, use $[varname] as an indicator of a variable containing a jQuery object (knowing your php background this can feel very strange in the beginning)
- creating a jQuery-Object is kind of heavy on the performance side so make sure you create them only once preferably